# Why does $\lim_{x\to0^{-}} \mathrm {Im}\left( \mathrm \ln \left(x\right)e^x\right)=\pi$?

Tags: limits, logarithms, exponential-function

Why does $$\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}  \mathrm {Im} \left( \ln\left(x\right) e^x\right)=\pi$$
Obviously this is no coincidence. I was thinking maybe this has to do with Euler's formula, but I don't see how the logarithm factors in. Does this even have to do with Euler's Formula?

Comment: Seeing as you're taking the logarithm of a negative real number here, it will depend on the choice of the branch of the logarithm you choose. In this domain $\operatorname{Log}$ (the principal branch, which agrees with the real logarithm on the positive reals) is not defined, so you would have to choose another one to get your result. Which branch are you using?

Comment: Since $e^x \to 1$, it can be thrown out of the limit expression. Now it's easier to see exactly why Ian's comment is more or less a full answer.

Comment: @Arthur, so if $e^x$ can be thrown out, focusing only on on the logarithm would be the same as $\mathrm {ln} (-1/n)$ as $n\to\infty$? Which would turn out to be $\mathrm{ln}(-1)-\mathrm{ln}(n)=i\pi-\mathrm{ln}(n)$ and since the second term is real, we are left with the answer?

Comment: @GuachoPerez Please see my answer, it's simpler (you don't have to substitute the reciprocal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For values of $x$ along the negative real axis, we can write $x=|x|e^{i(2\ell+1)\pi}$ for integer values of $\ell$.  Therefore, the multi-valued logarithm is given by

$$\log x=\log (|x|e^{i(2\ell +1)\pi})=\log |x|+i (2\ell+1) \pi)$$

Finally,

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{x\to 0^{-}} \text{Im}\left(\log(x) e^{x}\right)=(2\ell+1) \pi}$$

If we restrict ourselves to the principal branch of the complex logarithm, then

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{x\to 0^{-}} \text{Im}\left(\log(x) e^{x}\right)=\pi}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x \to 0^-}\ln x e^x \stackrel{e^x \to 1}{=}\lim_{x \to 0^-}\ln x = \lim_{x \to 0^+}\ln (-x) = \ln(-1) +  \lim_{x \to 0^+}\ln (x) $$

The real part of the final expression is undefined ($\lim_{x \to 0^+}\ln (x) = -\infty$), and the imaginary value depends on the branch under consideration. The imaginary part of the principal value is $\pi$ (because the principal value of $\ln(-1) = i\pi$).